# sendSignInLinkToEmail with Flutter, Firebase Auth throws error "[firebase_auth/missing-continue-uri] A continue URL must be provided in the request."

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Here's my code. I'm attempting to implement Firebase Passwordless Sign in.

```
final ActionCodeSettings acs = ActionCodeSettings(
        url: 'https://example.com/completeLogin}',
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        iOSBundleId: config.bundleId,
        androidPackageName: config.packageName,
        dynamicLinkDomain: config.firebaseDomain,
        androidInstallApp: true);

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
                              email: 'example@domain.com',
                              actionCodeSettings: acs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this,

`A valid continue URL must be provided in the request.`

Make sure that the URLs you are providing are valid.

Your URL has a `}` at the end - `url: 'https://example.com/completeLogin}'`, which is probably making it invalid.